# Use standard stylesheet with custom for Chatter VF page

Tags: chatter, visualforce-component, css

I am designing a custom styled vf page that will show the user's chatter feed. I am trying to use the chatter:feedWithFollowers component but all the styling goes away when I use the standardStylesheets="false" statement making it un-user-friendly. How do I keep the standard styles only on the chatter component?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a vf page with the chatter:feedWithFollowers component. On another page I embedded the chatter page in an iframe. The only downside to this is the embedded page will scroll as a page within a page, but this wasn't a big issue for my project.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If we use `standardStylesheets="false"` then it will remove all stylesheets for that particular VF page. You can try to enable stylesheet for while and copy all CSS of CHatter using some tools like Google Chrome Dev tools and then disable it. Once you have CSS copied you can use it in your page.