# EMBED CHATTER ON VISUALFORCE PAGE

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I am trying to embed Chatter on my custom `Visualforce Page`.

I saw a post here on this issue - see link below and would be grateful if you could send me the code and I will customize it for my use.

[Use standard stylesheet with custom for Chatter VF page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66058/use-standard-stylesheet-with-custom-for-chatter-vf-page?rq=1)

Comment: Martin - asking the community to send you code without demonstrating any effort on your part is not really Community etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple standard components that allow what you are looking for.

- The `<chatter:feed>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feed.htm)
- The `<chatter:feedWithFollowers>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_chatter_feedWithFollowers.htm)